# Check if String Does Not Contain Character

Tags: java, string, system, out, println

I need to see if a String does not contain nothing in Java. Here is my code:

```
public class Decipher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Opening...");
        System.out.println("Application Open");

        String s = "yyyd";
        if(s.contains("")){
            System.out.println("s contains Y");
            s =  s.replace("y", "a");
            System.out.println(s);
        }

    }

}
```

How can I get it to tell if s doesn't contain anything?

Comment: Read the javadoc. Also, `isEmpty()`.

Comment: s.charAt(an_int) == 'character'

Comment: `s.contains("")` is always true for a non-null String. Why not: `s.equals("")` or conversely, `!s.equals("")`?

Comment: I need to find if s is not equal to null

Comment: @user2455722 `s != null && !s.equals("")` will check for a non-null, non-empty string

Comment: Thanks I didn't even think of that. Wow I should have thought of that. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CommonsValidator -> GenericValidator](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/GenericValidator.html)

```
// returns true if 's' does not contain anything or is null
GenericValidator.isBlankOrNull(s)
```

And not depending on external libraries

```
if (s == null || s.trim().length() == 0) {
    // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: also org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils, which contains isBlank method

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking against a null value, then you can use

```
if (s != null) {
    dosomething();
}
```

If you want to check against an empty, instantiated string, then use

```
if (s.equals("") {
    doSomethingElse();
}
```

`null` strings and empty strings are two very different things.

Answer (score -1):

if im correct, you want to check if a string is empty right? 
The simplest way is like this

> if (string == null)

or, if you want to check if a string is null or has whitespace only

> if (string.trim() == null)

Comment: null and empty aren't the same thing